# Make drawable left to text in Textview in Android

Tags: android, xml

I have the Text View and a drawable which is a 'dot', now when I populate the Textview with Text, the drawable sometimes shift to extreme left when text is small , while sometimes near to text when text is large

I have made the drawable to left of TextView by android:drawableLeft="@drawable/blue"
I want to set to left just 8 density pixels before the text in textView
and when Text becomes 2 to 3 lines it comes in center of TextView I want it to be at left of First line.
please give any suggestions

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/numberLookup"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/blue"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: add `android:drawablePadding="8dp"` and you'll be OK

Comment: No Its not working :(

Comment: Can you please draw what you want and what you get

Comment: is `android:ems="10"` really needed?

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal behaviour of drawableLeft to alight to the most left corner. Instead, you can set an [ImageSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html) at the start of the text.

```
final Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(getText(R.string.yourText));
spannable.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spannable);
```

If you have a multiline text where every line should start with a dot drawable you can create a LeadingMarginSpan

```
public final class DotSpan implements LeadingMarginSpan {

    private final Bitmap mSpan;

    private final int mMargin;

    public DotSpan(final Bitmap span) {
        mSpan = span;
        mMargin = span.geWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public void drawLeadingMargin(Canvas c, Paint p, int x, int dir, int top,
            int baseline, int bottom, CharSequence text, int start, int end,
            boolean first, Layout layout)
    {
        if (first) {
            c.drawBitmap(mSpan, x, top, p); //not sure about coordinates if they are correct
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getLeadingMargin(boolean first)
    {
        return mMargin;
    }
}
```

And set it like

```
final Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(getText(R.string.yourMultilineText));
spannable.setSpan(new DotSpan(bitmap), 0, spannable.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spannable);
```

Comment: new ImageSpan(R.drawable.icon)error showing -- cannot convert icon to Bitmap

Comment: @Hitesh sorry, it should have been new ImageSpan(getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)); Updated my answer.